# C++ Read/write (shared) spinlock implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is my implementation of std compatible RWSpinLock using 2 atomics.

I think in cases when spinlock is free, it should take just 1 atomic write operation.

```
class RWSpinLock{
    std::atomic<int> readers_count{0};
    std::atomic<bool> write_now{false};
public:
    void lock() {
        while (!write_now.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)){
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }

        // wait for readers to exit
        while (readers_count != 0 ){
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
    void unlock() {
        write_now.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void lock_shared() {
        // unique_lock have priority
        while(true) {
            while (write_now) {     // wait for unlock
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }

            readers_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);

            if (write_now){
                // locked while transaction? Fallback. Go another round
                readers_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
            } else {
                // all ok
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    void unlock_shared() {
        readers_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

On `unique_lock` wait for write_now flag, then wait for readers_count.

On `shared_lock` wait for write_now flag, then increase readers_count. If during incrementation write_now flag becomes true, decrease readers_count and wait again for write_now (this should be relativley rare case).

P.S. I'm not sure though, about memory_order, and overall correctness (but seems fine to me).

Comment: Spin locks are not a good thing to implement. But this is not a spin lock because it yields `std::this_thread::yield();` A spin lock goes into a loop trying to acquire the lock (not yielding the thread just doing a busy wait).

Comment: @LokiAstari, I'd argue that this does count as a spinlock, since it doesn't sleep *for* any relevant period; it's morally equivalent in my mind to a spinlock on x86 that does `PAUSE` inside the inner loop. Even if it did `sleep_for(1s)` in the inner loop, I'd call it morally a spinlock, not a mutex. (The defining characteristic of a proper mutex, for me, is that it wakes up at the proper time and wastes a comparatively little amount of time polling in high-contention situations.) Maybe we can compromise and call this a "polling" mutex? :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock

Comment: @Loki Astari Let's consider that at all places where it yields, it first 40 cycles just spin, than go to yield. Consider yield just for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you have a one-character typo-bug here:

```
    while (!write_now.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)){
```

This should read

```
    while (write_now.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
```

— that is, "Put `true` into the `write_now` bit; and if it was already true, then wait. Only proceed if the old value was actually `false`."

What you have with the `!` is "Put `true` into the `write_now` bit; and if it was already true, then continue (oops!). Otherwise, yield once, and then continue anyway because *now* it'll be true for sure." ["For sure" here being a relative term. Obviously it won't be true if the old writer managed to finish and release the lock in the time we spent yielding.]

---

Performance nitpick: I've heard that it is useful to put one cache-line's worth of padding in between your two atomic variables, to eliminate [false sharing](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/false-sharing.html). Of course if you do that then your `shared_spinlock` class gets much bigger.

But if you *don't* do that, then all this fiddling with memory orders is useless, because your few `seq_cst` accesses to the shared cache line in `lock` and `lock_shared` will effectively `seq_cst` *all* your accesses in those functions.

As usual, I advise staying away from memory orders unless you're sure that you know what you're doing. That said, I *think* you're using them correctly here.

---

```
            if (write_now){
```

You might consider making this

```
            if (write_now.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
```

and likewise every other time you load an atomic variable without a memory order. As I said, normally I advise not to use memory orders other than `seq_cst` at all; but since you *are* using them, *maybe* it would be a good idea to mark every single load and store, consistently?

I also suspect that that particular load could be `memory_order_acquire` maybe, but seriously don't quote me on that. I have no idea.

---

```
    // unique_lock have priority
```

This comment should say `lock have priority`, or simply `writers have priority`.

---

C++ nitpick: Consider marking all of these member functions `noexcept`.

---

Functionality suggestion: Consider providing a way for a writer to atomically demote itself to a reader, without releasing the lock (i.e., without allowing some other writer B to sneak in and change the value that A just wrote). This should be possible, I think; and it's definitely not possible for anyone *but* you, the author of the mutex, to provide this functionality.

I think it's as simple as this:

```
void unlock_and_lock_shared() {
    readers_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
    write_now.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
}
```

The naming convention comes from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable.unlock_and_lock_shared).

Comment: Can you maybe suggest standalone header only RWSpinLock ? I found only folly https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/RWSpinLock.h, and that one was diffenetley not standalone .

Comment: @tower120: I have no special knowledge here; but how about just using [libc++'s C++17 `shared_mutex`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/shared_mutex)? I didn't verify, but it *looks* header-only, as long as you have a conforming `<mutex>` and `<condition_variable>` to use with it.  OTOH, that's a RWMutex, definitely not a RWSpinlock. I do tend to agree with Loki that "Spin locks are not a good thing to implement"...

Comment: Nah, I benchmarked libc++'s/gcc std lib/vs std lib shared_mutexes before. Spinlock, particularly this one , at least twice faster. "Spin locks are not a good thing to implement" - what does this mean?